# how to get only components from a folder using coreservices

Tags: 2013, core-service

I have a folder, which has subfolders and components. Now i want to retrieve only the components which uses a specified schema.How do i do it using core services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client;            

...

            string folderUri = "";
            string schemaUri = "";

            OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
            filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Component };
            filter.ComponentTypes = new ComponentType[] { ComponentType.Normal };
            filter.Recursive = true;

            XElement items = Client.GetListXml(folderUri, filter);
            foreach (XElement item in items.Elements())
            {
                ComponentData component = Client.Read(item.Attribute("ID").Value, null) as ComponentData;

                if (component.Schema.IdRef.Equals(schemaUri))
                {

                    // Do something with components of specific schema 

                }

            }
```

Client variable is of type SessionAwareCoreServiceClient. You can find more detailed explanation of code above on blog http://codedweapon.com/2013/03/changing-components-schemas-with-core-service/

Something similar was already asked on post [Get all component from selected folder and subfolder based on Schema](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/9693/get-all-component-from-selected-folder-and-subfolder-based-on-schema)